# Keyboard shortcut for debian app "Characters"

Tags: debian, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using sort of bare-bones Debian, the latest OS where there is an application viz "Characters v45.0" (a GNOME project which is coded by Daiki Ueno and Giovanni Campagna, and designed by Allan Day and Jakub Steiner).

I want to add it as an application with a keyboard shortcut to get emoji and special characters faster while typing. Can you suggest a way to make a keyboard shortcut from the settings in the layout in the picture below?

What should be put in there?
[image: Settings for keyboard shortcuts][image: Characters app in Gnome]

Answer (score 0):

*I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, Debian derivate, so the following might differ a bit.*

First you have to locate the binary / executable; easiest done with `locate`, which of some reason
isn't installed by default (on Ubuntu), so:

Open a terminal (e.g. a Bash prompt) and type what is shown below
*(hitting ENTER at the end of each line)*...

First to check if `locate` is available; type `$ locate` and hit ENTER, if that prints something like `command not found` then the first two commands below is to get it installed and it's database updated / initialized   *(you will be asked to type your password for both)*.

```
$ sudo apt install mlocate
...

$ sudo updatedb
...

$ locate characters | grep gnome
/usr/bin/gnome-characters
/usr/share/doc/gnome-characters
...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gnome-characters.md5sums
```

Files in /usr/bin/ (one of the bin dirs generally) are most likely actual executables, to verify this (here)
`$ which gnome-characters` is likely to print `/usr/bin/gnome-characters`, and just `gnome-characters` should start it.

Copy   *(SHIFT+CTRL+C to copy in the Terminal)*
and paste   *(CTRL+V in the GUI)*
`/usr/bin/gnome-characters` into the "Command" field
and then click "Add"; this will is most likely allow you to define a keyboard shortcut to use.
  *(Which I cannot check/verify/show due to being on Ubuntu)*

Comment: your solution worked in the end. I just had to install "locate" package in my OS repo and after that ```sudo updatedb``` didn't work for me but I just used ```sudo apt update```.